# How this C code works?

Tags: c

I've encountered to this following code during my C learning. I've paste it into CodeBlocks therefore I know the output but (here's my question) how it's done? Can you explain it to me?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char t[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    unsigned short *w;
    w = (unsigned int*) &t;
    printf("%d\n",*w++);
    printf("%d\n",*w++);
    printf("%d\n",*w++);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should learn about pointers

Comment: And how numbers are stored in memory (big endian/little endian)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beware that this code, as is, contains errors: bad cast, undefined behavior and platform dependent results...

This is pointer arithmetic. `w` initially points to the content at the address of the first element of `t` (this is what `w = (unsigned short *)&t` means). Then, hereafter, you access this memory as containing successives `short`s. At the same time the pointer is moved from a `short` to its successor.

Comment: Also result is going to be different depending on architecture

Comment: Well this could work, but the thing is `w` is cast to an `unsigned int*`, I think it's broken

Comment: OP just want to understand the logic, I said that details are wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that the code you've posted has problems; I would not take it as an example of well-written code.  Aside from the outright mistakes, it's unsafe in general.

First, let's at least make the types consistent; we'll assume the intent was to use `unsigned short` instead of `unsigned int`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char t[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    unsigned short *w;
    w = (unsigned short *) t; 
    printf("%hu\n",*w++);
    printf("%hu\n",*w++);
    printf("%hu\n",*w++);

    return 0;
}
```

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize an array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element in the array.

So, in the line

```
w = (unsigned short *) t;
```

the expression `t` is converted from "10-element array of `unsigned char`" to "pointer to `unsigned char`", and the value of the expression is the address of `t[0]`<sup>1</sup>.  We assign this pointer value to `w`, but we treat is as a pointer to `unsigned short` instead of `unsigned char` (this is known as type punning).  IOW, we're now treating `t` as a 5-element array of `unsigned short` instead of a 10-element array of `unsigned char`<sup>2</sup>.

The line

```
printf("%hu\n",*w++);
```

prints out the `unsigned short` value to which `w` is currently pointing<sup>3</sup>, and then advances `w` to point to the *next* unsigned short value (which corresponds to `t[2]`)<sup>4</sup>.

You'll get different output depending on whether your platform is big-endian or little-endian (that's one of the reasons this code isn't a great example).

---

<sup>1. Note that the expression `&t` would have given us the same *value* as `t` (the address of the first element of the array is the same as the address of the array), but the type would have been "pointer to 10-element array of `char`", or `char (*)[10]`, which isn't what we want here.


2. We are assuming that one `unsigned short` maps onto two `unsigned char`.  This is *usually* the case, but it doesn't have to be; shorts *may* be wider than two chars.


3.  The conversion specifier `%d` expects the corresponding argument to have type `int`; to print out an `unsigned short` value, use `%hu`. 


4.  Pointer arithemtic is done based on the size of the pointed-to type; `w++` will cause `w` to point to the next *object* of type `unsigned short`, which is at least two bytes.  Again, we're assuming in this case that `unsigned short` maps onto two `unsigned char`s.</sup>

Comment: 5. The code also assumes that the first element of the array `unsigned char t[10]` is suitably aligned for access via a `unsigned short *`. If the execution environment requires an `unsigned short *` to lie on an `unsigned short`-sized boundary in order to dereference it successfully, it may fail at runtime (or possibly at compilation time) if the compiler placed the start of array `t` between two `unsigned short`-sized boundaries.

Answer (score -1):

change these lines:

```
unsigned short *w;
w = (unsigned int*) &t;
```

with:

```
unsigned char *w;
w = (unsigned char*) &t;
```

and you'll get the values stored in the array:

```
0
1
2
```

Comment: or change the lines: